# API logs in aws cloudwatch for node js application

Tags: node.js, aws-sdk-js, aws-sdk-nodejs

How to store my API logs in aws cloudwatch? My application is running in appname.domain.com. I would like to log all the API request in aws cloudwatcher. Is there any documentation available to explore about it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use  packages like winston-cloudwatch